# Using multiple modifier symbols in autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to autohotkey and I got stuck since other at the following, quite simple problem:

I want to map Alt + Shift + b to the c key.

And the following code:

```
!+b::c
```

(That is the whole script)

Doesn't work. When I press Alt + Shift + b at the same time, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!+b::c` means as much as "when `alt shift b` is pressed, do `c`". But `c` is no action. State `send c` instead:

```
!+b::send c
```

Also note that when you want to execute more than just one send command, you can also expand the trunk and finish it with a return:

```
!+b::
send c
msgBox, other things
return
```

edit - wait a minute. If I remember right, `a::b` is a remapping of the `a` key to behave like `b`. So `!+b::c` should also work, shouldn't it. I'm confused now.

edit - well `!+b::c` does not send `c` but it sends `!+c`. This does not make any sense